# How to move a div (containing image) inside another div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to move an image div to some other div with effects and animation.
How I can do this?

My Code:

```
    var div2Pos = $("#marque").position();
    var div2Width = $("#marque").css("width");
    var div2Height = $("#marque").css("height");

    $("#img-div").animate({'left':div2Pos.left, 'width':div2Width, 'height':div2Height}, 1000);
```

where '#marque' is my destination div and '#image-div' is my original div

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use jQuery Dran n Drop.

Comment: You should write some code. Some jQuery tutorials and the jQuery manual would help a lot. This kind of question is not welcome here on SO, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make the element absalut animate it to the absalout position of the destnation and when anaimation end  remove and append the elemt and remove absalut position

```
          var des = $(".destnation").position();
        var el = $(".toMove");
        el.css("position", "absolute");
        el.animate({ top: des.top+"px" ,left :des.left+"px"}, 2000, undefined, function () {
            el.remove().appendTo(".destnation").css("position", "static");
        });
```

see fiddler example
http://jsfiddle.net/yamsalm/3U52z/

Comment: Thanks a lot bro... You made it possible for :)

Comment: Hey buddy, facing an issue in above code... if I iterate above code twice (for appending two ".toMove" divs to same ".destination" div), only one ".toMove" div appends to ".destination" div... while I need to append 2 ".toMove" divs to ".destination" div. Can u help???      Also, what is the purpose of `remove()` in `el.remove().appendTo(".destnation").css("position", "static");
` ?