# Rescaling Image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am rescaling an image on my website (depending on the screen size) with javascript using jQuery's .css() function.
Now I'm trying to animate a bunch of rescaled images and the performance crushes on older systems...
My guess is that the browser rescales the image in every step of the animation.
Is there any way to prevent that, e.g. by once rescaling the image and using this rescaled version for the animation?

Max

EDIT:

```
function adjustTile(contentHeight)
{
    TILE_GLOBAL.values.tileWidth = contentHeight/TILE_GLOBAL.def.tileWidthRatio;
    var windowWidth = jq(window).width();
    var tileStackDistance = windowWidth / TILE_GLOBAL.values.tiles.length / 3;
    var tileOffset = (windowWidth - TILE_GLOBAL.values.tileWidth - tileStackDistance*(TILE_GLOBAL.values.tiles.length-1))/2;


for(var i = 0; i < TILE_GLOBAL.values.tiles.length; i++)
{
    var position = tileOffset + tileStackDistance * i;
    jq(TILE_GLOBAL.values.tiles[i]) .css({  'left' : position + 'px', 
                                            'z-index' : TILE_GLOBAL.values.tiles.length - i, 
                                            'width' : TILE_GLOBAL.values.tileWidth + 'px', 
                                            'height' : contentHeight + 'px',
                                            'border' : TILE_GLOBAL.values.tileBorderSize + 'px solid #a3aba5'})
                                    .attr('data-original_pos', position);
}
jq('.tile-description').css({'font-size' : contentHeight / 20 + 'px'});
}

function slideTiles(e)
{
    TILE_GLOBAL.values.cancelReset = true;
    var chosenTile = jq(e.delegateTarget);
    var prevTiles = chosenTile.prevAll('div');
    var nextTiles = chosenTile.nextAll('div');

    for(var i = 0; i < prevTiles.length; i++)
    {
        jq(prevTiles[i]).animate({left :  jq(prevTiles[i]).attr('data-original_pos') - (TILE_GLOBAL.values.tileWidth/3*2.5) + 'px'}, {queue : false});
    }

    chosenTile.animate({left :  chosenTile.attr('data-original_pos') + 'px'}, {queue : false});

    for(var i = 0; i < nextTiles.length; i++)
    {
        jq(nextTiles[i]).animate({left :  jq(nextTiles[i]).attr('data-original_pos') + 'px'}, {queue : false});
    }
}


<div class="tile"><a href="isiplan-rv.html" target="_self"><img class="tile-image" src="images/template/tiles/rvtile.jpg" border="0" /></a>
<div class="tile-overlay"> </div>
<img class="tile-product-headline" src="images/template/tiles/rvheadline.png" border="0" />
<div class="tile-shadow"> </div>
<p class="tile-description"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: And please paste some code or set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: If your issue is not solved, you should respond which further issues, if solved, you should accept some answer so that others can know that thread is closed

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue....

You should place your rescaled image into a div that should has fixed width and height as per image size and should move that div (it will move image inside it), instead of image only.

OR

Even you can rescale the div size as per screen size and can specify height/width of image as 100% and can move div.

For your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428719/how-to-move-a-div-containing-image-inside-another-div-using-jquery)